Why does a fluid's velocity affect the fluid's incompressiblity?
First of all, I'm a complete beginner of fluid dynamics, and I'm taking a course of it because it is compulsory. Please be kind.
I'm told that a fluid is incompressible if the volume of any fluid element stays constant throughout the motion.
I'm also told that there is an assumption for the incompressibility to be a good approximation to fluids in real life: the fluid flows at a lower speed than the speed of sound. Here is what gets me utterly confused: why the incompressibility has to do with the fluid's velocity, since the definition does not seem to relate? And why the speed of sound rather than, say, light?
I'm trying to naively relate compressibility with speed: a high speed implies a high momentum, and intuitively that induces a high pressure if the fluid were to hit something, and a high pressure feels like a high probability to compress the fluid, so there must be an upper limit of the flow speed?
I'm okay with mathematical explanation but not too heavy please. A more intuitive explanation would be great. Thank you.

related: How can flows of gases at low Mach number have approximately constant density despite varying pressure?, i.e. what you talk about is pseudo-incompressibility condition at low Mach numbers : $\nabla \cdot \left(\alpha \mathbf {u} \right)=\beta$ where $\alpha, \beta \gt 0$.
